# Trigger jobs in gitlab-ci on merge request

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

It's posible run a job from gitlab-ci only on merge request?
Now, we have a big monolitic project with heavy tests, but we only want to run the test before merging to the branch master.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is now possible. This has been [introduced](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/merge_request_pipelines/index.html) in GitLab 11.6.

Answer (score 15):

Well, it's not built in currently however it's not impossible to do it yourself. Gitlab allows to [trigger](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/triggers/README.html#triggering-jobs-through-the-api) a job. It also supports [webhooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) on merge requests. However webhooks don't support variable in URIs and triggers can't read request body so you'd have to create a script that will act like a middle-man here:

1. Webhook on merge request calls to your script
2. Script parses the request and calls a triggers in gitlab with correct REF
3. Trigger runs the job that is marked with;

   only:
     -triggers

It's a bit hacky but it's working and easy to implement.

Comment: How can I parse the request with the script? Where I have to place the script?

Comment: @CescoBagnoli you need a web server that is accessible to your gitlab ci instance and some server side scripting to do it. You could use Lambda. You could use this gh project: https://github.com/MelwinKfr/gitlab-webhook-translator

Answer (score 4):

For the moment, no.
You should subscribe [the issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23902) to see if and when they will be available (and if your company is a enterprise customer, maybe you can contact them to ask to prioritize the implementation)