# How to trigger a bash script only after a merge request is merged?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've written a simple `gitlab-ci.yml` like this.

```
job1:
  script: 
  - echo hello
```

Currently, the script got triggered whenever a commit is pushed to any branches.

How can I configure gitlab-ci to make this script triggered only after a merge request is merged into the master branch?

I cannot find how to achieve my goal in the [`only`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only-and-except-simplified) key word.

There's a `Merge request events` option in `Settings -> Integrations` page, which seems to provide the function that is close to what I want.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918324/trigger-jobs-in-gitlab-ci-on-merge-request

Comment: That question is about triggering jobs BEFORE a merge request, which is a little bit different from mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918324/trigger-jobs-in-gitlab-ci-on-merge-request), I use [gitlab-webhook-translator](https://github.com/MelwinKfr/gitlab-webhook-translator) to trigger the script after a merge request is merged.

The key point here is to set the condition to `":object_kind == 'merge_request' && :object_attributes.work_in_progress === false && :object_attributes.state == 'merged'"`.

Another thing I want to mention is that we have to check `Allow requests to the local network from hooks and services` box in gitlab so that we can use gitlab wbehooks.

[image]

I use [a simple web server](https://gist.github.com/huyng/814831) to inspect the requests sent from gitlab. This is how I discovered `:object_attributes.state == 'merged'` option for the condition of gitlab-webhook-translator.